# Efficient evaluation of the inverse of a triangular matrix on a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I have this matrix that interests me. It arises when we try to express the norm of a $(p,p)$-form on an $n$-dimensional vector space in terms of (squares of) traces of the form with respect to the Lefschetz operator on the space. It's coefficients are these:
$$
a_{jk} = \begin{cases}
(-1)^k\tbinom{p-k}j \tbinom{n-j-k-p}{n-2p} \tbinom{n-k-p+j}{j} & \hbox{ if $j + k \leq p$,} \\
0 & \hbox{else.}
\end{cases}
$$
Here $j,k$ run between $0$ and $p$, so this is a $(p+1)\times(p+1)$ matrix. (We assume $2p \leq n$ so we don't run into trouble in the binomial coefficients.) For $p = 1$ it looks like this:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
n-1 & -1 \\ n & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In general $A$ is a triangular matrix (<strike>we could rearrange the bases here so it would be upper-triangular</strike> - wrong, but it wasn't important) and thus has a triangular inverse (its determinant is always nonzero).

I *really* want to calculate $v = A^{-1}(1,\ldots,1)$. I hope (against hope) that the mess of binomial coefficients in the result simplifies (there's some evidence for this when $p=1,2$) but to see that I have to be able to actually calculate $v$. I stress that I really don't care about $A^{-1}$ itself or its value on any other vector than $(1,\ldots,1)$.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Calculating $A^{-1}$ directly is probably out of the question, but maybe there's a nice trick to get the value of an inverse on a given vector?

Comment: I don't think you can make, say, $\pmatrix{0&1\cr-1&0\cr}$ upper-triangular by changing the basis (unless you're willing to go complex).

Comment: Solving a triangular system... so this would be a substitution method?

Comment: Gerry: Oops. No matter, at least the inverse is easy to calculate. :)
Pavel: I suppose, but actually carrying it out with those coefficients would be monstrous.

Comment: In the end I think Cramer's rule (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule) and brute force calculations do what I want since the matrix is (skewed) triagonal.